# EntityFramework connection to Oracle using Devart not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, devart

I am trying to connect to a oracle database using Devart, from an MVC application with EntityFramework.

I downloaded and installed Devart dotConnect, and added the following in the web config:

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.Oracle" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices, 
  Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=8.4.215.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
</providers>
```

and

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="user id=hr;password=hr;server=localhost;direct=True;sid=xe;persist security info=True" providerName="Devart.Data.Oracle"/>
```

But I still get this error:

> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type
>   'Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices,
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=8.5.558.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701' did not return an object that
>   inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'.
>   Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the
>   'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider.
>   This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6
>   or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

I've tried adding the dll references from devart in the project, but still the same problem.

**Any idea what I have to do in order to connect to the oracle database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed v8.5.558, haven't you? (basing on the error message)

Replace

```
Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=8.4.215.6
```

with

```
Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=8.5.558.6
```

in your web.config. Does this fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you.